# Apache Cassandra integration with Apache Solr

Tags: solr, cassandra

I'm familiar with Apache Solr on an MSSQL database, but now I'm looking how I can integrate Apache Solr with Apache Cassandra instead of my MSSQL database.

I'm looking for tutorials and first steps setting up this integration, but can't find anything useful.

With an MSSQLDB my data-config would look like this for example:

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test" user="sa" password="74667fghbjj3" />
<document name="cameras">
    <entity name="camera" query="select * from cameras WHERE isapproved='true'"
    deltaImportQuery="select * from cameras WHERE updatedate &lt; getdate() AND isapproved='true' AND id='${dataimporter.delta.id}'"
    deltaQuery="select id from cameras where isapproved='true' AND updatedate &gt; '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">              
        <field name="id" column="ID" />
        <field name="title" column="TITLE" />
        <field name="friendlyurl" column="FRIENDLYURL" />           

        <entity name="camera_country" query="select countryid from cameras where id=${camera.id}">
            <entity name="countries" query="select title_nl as country_nl,title_en as country_en from countries where id = ${camera_country.countryid}">
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

But how would I go about this using Cassandra as my NOSQL DB?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you figure out, how to integrate without using DSE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solandra was an open-source hobby project by Jake Luciani.  He tells the history of Solandra and led the development of DSE Search, the next generation of Solandra.  He talks about it in this [blog post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-with-solr-integration-details).  It's the best way that I know of to use the regular Solr 4 interface with Cassandra to replicate the data and provide things like fault tolerance.  You can download it to try it out for free and DataStax does have special pricing for startups, for what it's worth.  It's just that DataStax had to justify investing resources in it.  For more details on it, see [the docs](http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise2.1/search/index).  Disclaimer, I do work for DataStax.

Comment: Thanks. But my budget is extremely low, I don't have an investor and am just by myself, so unfortunately I don't think DataStax is a match for me. 
I'm just extremely surprised that I haven't found any solutions for this setup provided by the Apache Foundation itself!

Comment: FYI, the blog post link is broken - the datastax comparison of solr vs dse search is [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/searchOssSolrDiff.html)

Comment: @Flo could you find a solution how to integrate solr with cassandra without DSE ?

Comment: @AbdelazizMokhnache unfortunately no. I went with an MSSQL database solution in the end since it has caught up massively with NOSQL databases feature and performance wise.

Comment: @Flo thanks a lot for your reply .. but that's a pitty, that shouldn't be the case since they are both apache products :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do a drop in replacement, but have a look at [Solandra](https://github.com/tjake/Solandra) it might do what you need. Also Datastax has a solr+cassandra product called enterprise search; it looks pretty good, but you have to pay for it.

Comment: what do you mean by "drop in replacement"? Solandra seems to lack a bit of sustainability and I don't have the budget for Datastax.
Is my question so special? It seems to me that Cassandra for data-storage and Solr for facets and search would be a pretty common scenario would it not?

Comment: I mean i don't think you can use cassandra as a drop in replacement for SQLServer. The queries you have wouldn't work as is, but it might be possible to tweak them. I'm not familiar enough with solr to know. Have a look at Cassandra-JDBC (http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/) for the JDBC drivers and try it out

Comment: It's not that I want to replace an existing MSSQL DB, I just wanted to know IF I can use Cassandra instead of MSSQL in future projects (sorry for the confusion). So it would not be a drop in replacement: I want a new project with just cassandra+solr. I'm kind of surprised that I haven't found any solutions provided by the Apache Foundation!

Comment: Yes exactly, hence my "it's not a drop in replacement" comment. If you were replacing MSSQL with another relational database, that would be a drop in replacement. That's not to say that cassandra won't work, just that you'll have to do some tweaking to get it to work. Check out the JDBC driver and give it a whirl - it may be pretty easy

Comment: I'm not replacing anything, I'm starting something new. So all options are on the table now.
The JDBC driver won't be useful when I'm starting a new project using just Cassandra+Solr right?
Thanks!

Comment: I think we just mean different things when talking about a drop in replacement. I see your point about this being new development - but personally it's a phrase I use to mean one thing that can directly replace another - regardless of its deployment state. Anyway, that aside, the cassandra JDBC driver will still be useful to you in your new project.

Comment: Ah thanks for clarifying. Looking at that JDBC driver 2 questions pop in mind:
1. is that JDBC driver compatible with .NET? (.NET would be my preferred higher client to access Cassandra when writing to it)>
2. If I add the JDBC driver to my Solr data-config.xml I could also add CQL statements in there (instead of SQL as I do now).

Thanks again!

Comment: 1 - I haven't tried it, but should work. 2 - same answer as 1 :)